# having trouble writing JS tests

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine

I am writing jasmine tests for the following JavaScript method.

```
register: function (module, obj) {
    if (this._isString(module) && this._isObject(obj)) {
        if (!this._isMethod(obj.init)) {
            this._log(3, 'Module does not have init function');
            return;
        }
        // If modules object inside modulesData does not exist then create one
        if (typeof this.modulesData.modules === 'undefined') this.modulesData['modules'] = {};
        this.modulesData.modules[module] = obj; // Store module's object inside modulesData.modules

        if (typeof this.modulesData.$container === 'undefined') this.modulesData['$container'] = {};
        this.modulesData['$container'] = $('#' + module);

        if (obj.events && typeof obj.events === 'object') {
            CORE.AggregatedEvents.init(obj);
        }
    } else {
        this._log(3, 'Module name should be String & obj should be Object');
    }
},
    //....rest code here
```

My current tests are as follow

```
describe('Have register method', function () {
    it('CORE should have register() method', function () {
        expect(CORE.register).toEqual(jasmine.any(Function));
    });

    it('register() should accept 2 arguments', function () {
        spyOn(CORE, 'register');
        CORE.register('moduleName', {});
        expect(CORE.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith('moduleName', {});
    });

    it('register() should accept string as first and Object as second argument', function () {
        spyOn(CORE, 'register');
        CORE.register('moduleName', {});
        expect(CORE.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(String), jasmine.any(Object));
    });
});
```

My above tests test for existence of register() method in Core. Then checks for number of arguments and types of arguments. My question is **how can I write Jasmine tests to test this method functionality?**

Comment: Invoke it and check the result?

Comment: I am new to testing. How can I do that?

Comment: You invoke the method, just the way you did here: `CORE.register('moduleName', {});`. Now - provide it with some testing object and test the results.